# Pass variable from one page to another using jquery mobile on windows phone7

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a jQuery mobile application for windows phone 7.  I have to pass data from one view to another via url on windows phone 7. for this we  try query string like this:

```
     $.mobile.changePage("test.html?id=0");
```

but that does not working on windows phone. Windows emulator showing error of loading. Please help me. Is there any another way of passing data between pages.

thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it should'nt be `changePage()` ?

Comment: yes it is changePage(). this is typing problem.but the problem is same.

Comment: use local storage for passing variable same as question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980869/passing-parameters-from-page-page-to-another-on-jquery-mobile-application/12313471#12313471

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know its too late to answer this question . But I am adding this answer so that others can find this helpful .

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", myMethod, false);
function myMethod(){

$("li").click(function(){


    var index = $(this).index();

    console.log("index"+ index);

    window.localStorage.setItem("date",userArray_date[index] );
    window.localStorage.setItem("title",userArray_title[index] );

window.location.href='mypage.html';
});}
```

and On `mypage.html:`

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", page2Method, false);

function page2Method(){

  var display_date = window.localStorage.getItem("date");
  var display_title = window.localStorage.getItem("title");

}
```