# Cordova localstorage not persisting

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I am developing an Hybrid Mobile app using Windows Phone 7 sdk and phonegap. Using Cordova local storage I am storing value. The stored value does not persist If I close the app and launch again in windows phone emulator. Anybody used local storage or alternative persistant storage in windows phone shares idea would be great.

```
window.localStorage.test = "Some test data";
console.log(window.localStorage.test) //It prints result but does not persist
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the correct syntax is:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("test", "Some test data");

console.log(window.localStorage.getItem("test"));
```

Assigning properties *appears* to work simply because javascript allows you to attach new properties to objects.

**Original Answer** Are you closing the emulator between executions? The emulator clears its user state when you close it.

Comment: No I did't close the emulator. I am using scenario like one time login I check login using local storage as a flag.

Comment: That is syntax supported by android and ios not for windows check this doc last paragraph http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980869/passing-parameters-from-one-page-to-another-in-jquery-mobile-application) seems to imply that the syntax is supported by WP7 (using _get/setItem_, though, not _Data_ as I originally wrote)

Comment: Your answer is right, above code was working fine and data persist. I miss understood and used wc3 local storage and it does not persist. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't **window.** localStorage() refer to the HTML5 localStorage? I think you should use just localStorage() to make use of Cordova's implementation.

Comment: Peeking at the Cordova 2.7.0 JS source looks like it patches `window.localStorage` in the event that it's not supported.