# Angularjs localStorage to store settings in cordova app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, settings, local-storage

I'm using AngularJS v1.2.7 with Cordova 3.3.0 (Android) I need to store some settings in the phone memory- so when the app/device restarts, the app can still have access to this stored data.

Any tutorials about this? I couldn't find any :(

Knowing that Cordova supports; LocalStorage, WebSQL ([no more maintained](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/#status-of-this-document)), IndexedDB ([not widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=indexeddb) by Opera and Safari). I tend to use LocalStorage but does it keep/remember the data even after I restart the device?

At the moment I'm using the answer [#12969480 by Richard Szalay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969407/cordova-localstorage-not-persisting#answer-12969480) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing a custom plugin and store the settings properly in the Objective-C user defaults.

LocalStorage is not permanent storage, and WebSQL seems like overkill for storing settings.

You don't have to get too involved in Objective-C and there are good Phonegap/Cordova plugin guides:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

I use this code to store a "FirstRun" variable to check if the app is a new install. The plugin checks if the app has been run before, and returns 1 or 0, which is parsed to an integer and evaluated as true/false.

You could update this code and add more methods to the "AppChecks" class. I put all simple checks and setting storage in this class.

AppChecks.h

```
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>

@interface AppChecks : CDVPlugin

- (void) checkFirstRun:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;

@end
```

AppChecks.m

```
#import "AppChecks.h"
#import <Cordova/CDVPluginResult.h>

@implementation AppChecks

- (void) checkFirstRun:(NSMutableArray *)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options {
NSString* callbackId = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];

CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
NSString* javaScript = nil;

@try {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *isFirstRun = @"1";

    if (![defaults objectForKey:@"firstRun"]) {
        [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstRun"];
    } else {
        isFirstRun = @"0";
    }

    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:isFirstRun];
    javaScript = [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:callbackId];
} @catch (NSException* exception) {
    // could not get locale
    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_JSON_EXCEPTION messageAsString:[exception reason]];
    javaScript = [pluginResult toErrorCallbackString:callbackId];
}
[self writeJavascript:javaScript];
}
@end
```

Used in my Javascript code:

```
cordova.exec(
    function( isFirstRun ) {
        isFirstRun = parseInt( isFirstRun );
        if( isFirstRun ) {
          // do stuff for first run
        }
    },
    function(err) {
        // handle error from plugin
    },
    "AppChecks",
    "checkFirstRun",
    []
);
```

Comment: You are right; LocalStorage is not permanent storage. I'll try your example even if I don't want to use Objective-C for this app.

Comment: Sorry I should update my answer so the plugin is written in Java instead, I've only implemented this as an Objective-C plugin but it could be converted to Java/Android. The Javascript portion would remain the same

Comment: My experience is only with Cordova 2.x and Android, but localStorage _was_ persisted between restarts (though not between re-installs).

Answer (score 3):

I was looking around for something similar for the hell of it. I found the following:

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angularLocalStorage

Example has a text box showing the saved state:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Y1mrNVRkInCItqvZXtto?p=preview

```
var eS = angular.module('exampleStore', ['localStorage']);

  eS.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','$store',function($scope, $store) {
      $store.bind($scope, 'propertyOnScope', 'My default value');

      $scope.clearTest = function(){ 
          $store.remove('propertyOnScope'); 
      };
  }]);
```

Comment: +1. Thanks fairweather. I found https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage to be a better alternative; No Getter 'n' Setter functions, just plain JS.

Comment: Cool. The nice thing about the module I found is that when the model changes, that variable is automatically saved. There are no getters or setters either; just a binding. Thanks for the bump.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage is translated to the native file system with Cordova, so in fact the data will persist for the life of the installation.

Check out [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/) from the [Drifty](http://drifty.com/) guys who created [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/).

These AngularJS Cordova wrappers make life just a little bit easier, if you're someone who wants to access native device functionality through Cordova, using AngularJS as your front end.

Also, check out their new web series, [the Ionic Show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJAWaE11Jf4). They talk about current, relevant tools for hybrid mobile app developers.

A basic tutorial for using localStorage with phonegap can be found [here](http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/developing-phonegap-mobile-project-part-3/)

Comment: do you have documentation or a reference that "LocalStorage is translated to native file system with Cordova?" Does Cordova change the path of webstorage? I know on iOS there was concerns that LocalStorage gets flushed when the device runs low on storage.